# Is there any way to create devtools panel on mobile chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-extension, pagespeed

I want to write an extension which can be used on mobile chrome, but it seems google doesn't supply a way to do that. So I was thinking to add my extension to developer tools panels using the api chrome.devtools.panels.create. For web page, my new panel can show on the dev tools panel bar, but for mobile chrome using adb to do a remote debug, my new panel won't appear on the dev tools panel. 
  At first I think it is a dead end, but after that I found extension "page speed" can be seen when using adb to do a remote debug. I copy the manifest.json content ,and replace it with my own content, but it still can't work.
  Does any one know how to write a extension/devtools panel to debug chorme mobile?

Comment: First of all did you try to debug your extension and remote devtools page?

Second: chrome for mobile generates a bootstrapping page by itself. The entire devtools page is fetching from the net. It could be a bit old version of devtools page.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but if you're ultimately looking for a way to get devtools on mobile, it's now possible on the latest Chrome stable (and newer) channels.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/mobile/

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot build extensions for mobile chrome at this time.  See the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/faq).

Comment: Looks like he is trying to implement an extension for devtools window which is connected to chrome for mobile via adb.